# Using sql transaction with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Firstly I should point out I am new to the world of php and MySql! I'm busy learning but I may not be doing things the professional way.

**Background**
I have created a php form that when submitted inserts data into two tables: post_header, post_details.

Currently I am issuing two insert statements in the format below:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO post_header (member_id, ....+more fields
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
 $insert_stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST[member_id]);

if ($insert_stmt->execute()){
 //it worked
 $newpostId=$mysqli->insert_id;
 //now use the header id (primary key from post_header, which auto-increments) to add a record into the detail table

 $sql="INSERT INTO post_detail (header_id, ....+more fields
 if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
  $insert_stmt->bind_param('i', $newpostId);
```

I should point out that post_header & post_detail have a 1 to 1 relationship and are linked by header_id.

My question is does PHP & MySQL have a way of letting me submit inserts into both tables within one sql transaction?

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: Mysqli does not have that capability at the moment, only using multi_query -> http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Unusually, this IS the professional way!

Comment: @PatrickGeyer unfortunately, you don't understand neither purpose of this function nor transactions.

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=mysqli+transaction ?

Comment: I only don't understand why you are binding only one parameter for the each query.

Comment: thank you for the responses. @Yourcommonsense this was just an example of what I'm doing not an exact copy and paste of my code.